# How to parse 2 columns of ints in a txt file

Tags: java, parsing, int

I was given a set of data in a .txt document in the form of:

```
0   1
0   3
0   4
0   5
0   6
0   7
```

... and so on

My question is, how can I parse this so that I put the left column of the integers in an array, and likewise for the right column of numbers.  Each pair of numbers has their own line.

In this set of data I have given, `int[] leftColumn` would be all zeroes and `int[] rightColumn` would contain 1, 3, 4, 5 ,6 ,7.

Answer (score 2):

[java.util.Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) already does most of the heavy lifting for you, it's just a matter of using it:

```
List<Integer> leftColumnTmp = new LinkedList<>();
List<Integer> rightColumnTmp = new LinkedList<>();
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner("myfile.txt")) {
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        leftColumnTmp.add(sc.nextInt());
        rightColumnTmp.add(sc.nextInt());
    }
}

int[] leftColumn = leftColumnTmp.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
int[] rightColumn = rightColumnTmp.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
```

Comment: I get this error "The method stream() is undefined for the type List<Integer>".

Comment: Works only on Java 8 & above.

Comment: @AniMenon yup, this is an in modern Java. Note, however, that the only part that requires Java 8 there is the last two statements that convert a `List<Integer>` to an `int[]`. If you don't want to rely on Java 8 you could do this yourself using a `for` loop or use a third party like Apache Commons Lang's ArrayUtils

Answer (score 0):

Read the file line by line and split lines by space, then add them to the arrays.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(<PATH/TO/FILE>));
try {
    String line = br.readLine();
    List<Integer> leftColumn = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> rightColumn = new ArrayList<>();
    while (line != null) {

        String strarray[] = line.split(" ");
        for (int count = 0; count < strarray.length ; count++) {
            leftColumn.add(Integer.parseInt(strarray[count]));
            rightColumn.add(Integer.parseInt(strarray[++count]));
        }
        line = br.readLine();
    }
    System.out.println("Left Column :"+leftColumn);
    System.out.println("Right Column :"+rightColumn);
}finally {
    br.close();
}
```

Comment: @slartidan removed `sb`

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way of reading files, when using java8:

```
List<Integer> left = new ArrayList(); 
List<Integer> right = new ArrayList();

Files.lines(Paths.get("c:\\lines.txt"))
    .map(l -> l.split("\\s")) 
    .forEachOrdered(l -> {
        left.add(Integer.parseInt(l[0]));
        right.add(Integer.parseInt(l[1]));
   });
```

If you really need to `int[]`s, you can convert it later on:

```
int[] leftArray = left.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
int[] rightArray = right.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
```